# Difference in UITableViewCell willMoveToSuperview: behavior between iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: ios5, uitableview, ios6

Under iOS 5, it seemed that a `UITableViewCell` subclass's `willMoveToSuperview:` method was called every time the cell was used or reused, but under iOS 6, it seems that it's only called when the cell is initially created and used, not when a cell gets reused.  Can anyone verify this difference?  Is this a bug?

What method should I be using to do cell setup inside the `UITableViewCell` subclass that will get called when the cell is reused in both iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Comment: Verified. Same goes for didMoveToSuperview:. Messing with some animation code I have. Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if it's intended?

Comment: Add willMoveToWindow to that too.

Comment: The same is valid for UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue with UICollectionView. It seems you have to implement the method `prepareForReuse` in the view you are using for display (ex. of type UITableViewCell or a UICollectionViewCell). However, this also gets called even if it is the first time creating a cell (not just when it is being reused) if you are using the new `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` with a registered class with `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` in iOS6.

Reference: [UITableViewCell Class - prepareForReuse](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW33)

Answer (score 0):

### 1. How to know if a cell is removed from tableview?

use this method to do something, e.g. cleanup, stop timers or something else...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

### 2. how to know if a cell is going to be displayed

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

### 3. how to know if a cell is going to reuse

override this method

```
UITableViewCell:
 - (void)prepareForReuse();
```